# subjunctife or infinitive what is the difference?

Tags: subjunctives

Is there a difference in the meaning between:

> I would **prefer you to do** that.
>
> I would **prefer that you do** that. *(more polite)*

Comment: I don't follow you. There is no subjunctive clause in either of your examples.

Comment: @BillJ That I think depends on whether you regard "subjunctivity" as a property of the verbform or of the clause.

Comment: or should have I written I would prefer that she do  that

Comment: @StoneyB  I take 'subjunctive' as a clause type headed by a plain form verb.

Comment: @BillJ Then what compels you to reject *that you do that* as non-subjunctive, given that with a 3sg subject it would elicit the unambiguously subjunctive *that she do that*?

Comment: Could you let me know the difference

Comment: @StoneyB  So which of the OP's two examples do you see as being an unabiguously subjunctive clause, bearing in mind that the subject is 2nd person?

Comment: @user5577 The subjunctive is overtly distinct from the present tense only with the verb "be" or a 3rd person singular subject, neither of which is the case with your example (it's not "be", and it's 2nd person), so it's not unambiguously subjunctive. Your suggested alternant of "I would prefer that she do that" is unambiguously subjunctive.

Comment: but is there a difference in the meaning between these two sentences or do they mean the same thing

Comment: @BillJ Well, that's why I asked my first question. For *me*, 'subjunctive' is a property of the clause, so I unhesitatingly read *that you do that* as 'subjunctive' because I know (from familiarity with the paradigm) that that's a sort of clause that *prefer* licenses, alongside *that you did that*, *that you would do that* and *(for) you to do that*.

Answer (score 1):

There is no substantial difference in meaning. The difference in 'politeness' is a matter of making your preference less demanding with a construction that emphasizes its tentative or hypothetical character. There are lots of these hedges:

> I prefer you to do that
>   I *would* prefer you to do that.
>   I *would* prefer *for you to do that*.
>   I *would* prefer you *did* that.
>   I *would* prefer it *if you would do that*.
>   I *would* prefer it *if you did that*.
>   I *would* prefer (that) you *do* that. . . and so forth.

They all amount to pretty much the same thing—and in speech their 'politeness' can be overridden by tone of voice.

Comment: I would prefer that she do that and I would prefer that she did  .Are both sentences subjunctives? .Why is  it do for the first one and did for the second one

Comment: @user5577 I'm not really fond of the term 'subjunctive' anyway, but no, I would not follow traditional grammar and call *did* a past subjunctive. It's just an irrealis use of the past form of the verb.

Comment: So do they mean the same thing

Comment: @user5577 I think I said exactly that.